# How to render reflections only

Tags: rendering, transparency

[image]Hello I am trying to render a scene that I want reflections of a plane rendered only (I want the plane to be invisible) I did watch this video and my item didn't have IndexOB https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wjWoglMYXBE
tbh I want this for an isometric item for creating a game which reflections and the image are necessary so i can use a png file only please help thanks.

Comment: It would be helpful for us if you could add images that show what you are trying to accomplish and maybe your .blend file, so we can take a look inside as well.

Comment: Edit: image added i guess you understand what do I want to do I can't do it better sry

Comment: So it's the background plane with the rural scene that's to be masked out, or is it the orange thing in the center?

Comment: Yes i want to mask out the plain I just want to get rid of the plane

Comment: From the video link it appears you just want to place a 3D model "into" a photo, complete with it's reflection.  That's easy if you can substitute the lake for one produced in Blender.  That would do all the reflecting you want. If the boat and trees on this side are also required, some extra and careful masking could bring those back also.

Comment: @Covero, have placed a small video on Dropbox, see it this is what you want.  If you're asked to sign in, just click in an empty space.  The file can be downloaded for better viewing.
The water is animated with small ripples and I haven't masked anything out, just replaced the lake so the orange object can be reflected.  
Any model you "fly over" the lake will also be reflected.

The link - https://www.dropbox.com/s/v15qq7vzgatjgn7/LakeRipple.mp4?dl=0